# Dining Philosopers changes

Tags: c, linux

This was a homework question and I got it wrong. I really want to understand the solution for this question. Original code state:

`The solution presented in Fig. 2-46 is deadlock-free and allows the maximum parallelism for an arbitrary number of philosophers. It uses an array, state, to keep track of whether a philosopher is eating, thinking, or hungry (trying to acquire forks). A philosopher may only move into eating state if neither neighbor is eating. Philosopher i's neighbors are defined by the macros LEFT and RIGHT. In other words, if i is 2, LEFT is 1 and RIGHT is 3. The program uses an array of semaphores, one per philosopher, so hungry philosophers can block if the needed forks are busy.`

[image]

`Question: Consider the procedure put_forks in Fig. 2-46. Suppose that the variable state[i] was set to THINKING after the two calls to test, rather than before. How would this change affect the solution?`

Comment: The dining philosophers all wait until Bruce Schneier has been served.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a concrete programming/code question but about computer science theory and an homework implementation of a classical CS example. Those problems are best discussed on the dedicated computer science StackExchange site https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's about a code implementation of the traditional computer science problem, not about the problem itself.

Comment: And in fact, having read the code and given an answer, the question is not actually about the dining philosophers CS problem at all!  A key part of the dining philosophers problem is avoidance of deadlock due to sequential locking of multiple resources, those being the right fork and the left fork for each philosopher.  This code assumes that getting both forks is atomic, so it doesn't address the core issue in the dining philosophers problem at all.  The only similarity is the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the state change in put_forks is moved to after the tests, the philosopher in question will still be in an EATING state during the tests, and neither of the adjacent philosophers will be able to change state to EATING.  This means that any philosopher that ever blocks because he gets hungry when an adjacent philosopher is eating - at the end of the take_forks method - will stay blocked forever.

Comment: I had a similar question and I found following two answers for this same problem in two different places. Could you please us if you think any of the following solutions are correct:

(1) If a philosopher blocks, neighbors can later see that she is hungry by checking his state, in test, so he can be awakened when the forks are available.

Comment: (2) The change would mean that after a philosopher stopped eating, neither of his neighbors could be chosen next. In fact, they would never be chosen. Suppose that philosopher 2 finished eating. He would run test for philosophers 1 and 3, and neither would be started, even though both were hungry and both forks were available. Similarly, if philosopher 4 finished eating, philosopher 3 would not be started. Nothing would start him.

Comment: @Learner_51 Your (1) is how the code provided in the problem originally works, without the change that introduces a bug.  Your (2) is another description of the bug that is introduced in that change.  Hope that helps.